# finish() call in android

Tags: android, kotlin

What happen if call finish() and switchactivity ??

```
 finish()
 switchActivity(SecondActivity::class.java)
```

In my case i want to destroy my first activity becasue no more need this also i want to use the data in my secondActivity which save in my firstactivity.
How can i do it ??

Comment: There is nothing named `SharedData` or `SharedData.Info` in the Android SDK. What are they?

Comment: Update my post , sorry for my ugly post.

Comment: Use intent to send data from one activity to another and in the end call finish(). This will send the data first through intent and then remove the first activity from stack.

Comment: I'm  try to save data in shared way that is used by all the activity.So update or save in firstactivity and use second activity. Main problem is here , Is saved data destroy after finish call ??

Comment: No, it doesn’t. I am assuming you are saving data in shared preferences or database, if so, then it will not be destroyed even if you close the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`finish()` can be called to kill (destroy) an `Activity` instance. If you don't need to close your `Activity` manually, which is true in many cases, you don't need to call this method.

But if you need a button in your `Activity` that says "close" or something like that then you should use this method. In general though the back button behavior in Android will handle things like this.

As for passing data between activities thats a completely different question

Depending on how much data you have to send you can pass something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Variable Name",string_to_be_sent);
startActivity(intent);
finish();//if you want to close previous activity.
```

then to get the information

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("Variable Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

**finish()** method is used to finish activity but write in the last.

Please check below ex.

```
  Intent intent=new Inent(currentActivity.this,otheractivity.class)
  startActivity(intent)
   **finish()** // last line
```